# How do I best sum bogomips?

Tags: linux, shell, central-processing-unit

I want to compare servers that run Linux (Centos) against each other - cpu wise.

I thought of taking the sum of all cpus bogomips for comparison, but could only come up with this ugly shell line:

```
echo 0 `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep bogomips | cut -d ":" -f 2 | tr " " "+" `| bc
```

(the 0 is needed because otherwise the line starts with + and is not suitable for bc)

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Why would you think that the number of millions of times a CPU can do absolutely nothing per second is any sort of a realistic, or even useful, benchmark?

Comment: `cat` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Ignacio: What would be a better benchmark? I just need a quick-and-easy way to half a bunch of servers into two halfs, each half should have approximately the same cpu power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F: '/bogomips/ {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: nice! Didn't know that it is so easy with awk - getting more and more "converted" :-)

Comment: On ARM it's `awk -F: '/[Bb]ogo[Mm][Ii][Pp][Ss]/ {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' /proc/cpuinfo` (BogoMIPS & bogomips)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne '
/^bogomips/ {
   s/^bogomips[ \t]\+:[ ]\+\([0-9.]\+\)/\1+/
   H
}
$ {
   g
   s/\n//g
   s/+$//
   p
}
d
' /proc/cpuinfo \
   | bc
```

without decimals:

```
echo $[`sed -ne '
/^bogomips/ {
   s/^bogomips[ \t]\+:[ ]\+\([0-9]\+\).*/\1+/
   H
}
$ {
   g
   s/\n//g
   s/+$//
   p
}
d
' /proc/cpuinfo`]
```

Comment: At least in Bash, the `$[]` form is deprecated. Use `$(())` instead.

Comment: It's probably not necessary to be so meticulous in your regex. The `d` is unnecessary. `sed -ne '/bogomips/ {s/^[^:]*:\(.*\)/\1+/;H}; ${g;s/\n//g;s/+$//;p}' /proc/cpuinfo | bc`

Answer (score 0):

Yours is fine (78 byte), it can be shortened by a small 
amount and linked to a single command (eg. perl)

`perl -ne's/mips\s*:\s*(\S+)/$i+=$1/eg; END{print$i}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Rounding is straightforward:

`perl -ne's/mips\s*:\s*(\S+)/$i+=$1/eg; END{print int($i+0.5)}' /proc/cpuinfo`

or, use the autosplit option on ':' (-F)

`perl -F: -ane '$i+=$F[1] if $F[0]=~/mips/; END{print $i}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Regards

rbo